# How can I change variable values of a java program through a web interface?

Tags: java, javascript, android, html

Is there a way to handle a java program (actually it is an android application) through a web interface..? My idea is to ask some parameter values such as background color, font-size etc.. and create a custom application to the user.Any ideas?
Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Write the values to a file, and have the Java program read them.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is pass in command-line parameters, that's what the (String[] args) parameter is for.  This assumes that there isn't anything I'm unaware of which rules out this sort of thing in interwebs-land, since I don't really have any experience with applets and such.  Assuming it is applicable to your application, when the program is called, add the parameters to the end, eg: `java.exe myApp "blue" "20px"` (or however web apps are invoked) would run the program with `args[0] = "blue"` and `args[1] = "20px"` I'm I'm off-base, and applets are totally different than what I am used to, feel free to ignore or chastise me at your leisure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change those variables while the app is running you could create appropriate functions in java and then call them from js using ajax. 
Otherwise the suggested answers (command-line arguments or using file) should be fine.